# Not able to delete string item with colon in python list

Tags: python

So I'm having the following problem while coding in python: I have a few string items in a list like so:

```
['X','Y','Z','A', 'B:C', 'D']
```

I want to delete everything past `'Z'`. I use the following code to attempt this:

```
for item in lines:
   if ((item == "A")):
      lines.remove(item)

   if (item == "B:C"):
      lines.remove(item)

   if (item == "D"):
      lines.remove(item)
```

`A` and `D` get removed perfectly. However, `B:C` is not removed and stays in the list...

Mind you, `A, D, B:C` etc represent strings, not characters (e.g. `A` could be `Transaction failed!` and `B:C` can represent `WRITE failure: cannot be done!`)

How can this be solved?

Comment: What about slicing? `lines[:1+lines.index('Z')]`

Comment: You shouldn't be modifying the list while iterating over it...

Comment: Could it be because you're iterating through the list, and once you remove an element (`'A'`), it skips past the next one?

Comment: I don't see why you iterate on it in the first place since you already know what you want to remove.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modifying a list while iterating over it is usually a bad thing.  Some of the elements get skipped when you remove the current element.  You *may* be able to fix it by iterating over `reversed(lines)`, but it is better to create a new list that doesn't have the elements that you want to drop:

```
to_remove = {'A', 'B:C', 'D'}
new_lines = [line for line in lines if line not in to_remove]
```

Or, if you want to modify in-place:

```
to_remove = {'A', 'B:C', 'D'}
lines[:] = [line for line in lines if line not in to_remove]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `.index()` method to find the index of a specific element inside a list.

Then after finding the `z_index`, you may create another list by slicing the first one.

Here's an example:

```
l1 = ['X','Y','Z','A', 'B:C', 'D']

#finding index of element 'Z'
z_index = l1.index('Z')

#slicing list from 0 until z_index
l2 = l1[:z_index]

print l2
```

Output:

```
['X', 'Y']
```

Comment: So I need to actually check for these strings first before I delete them. Like I need to check for "Transaction failed!" for example. So iteration is inevitable?

Comment: This is the correct solution if you need to slice up the list. If you're doing additional checks on the list for some reason, then use the list comprehension solution.

Comment: You should avoid iteration if you want to remove items inside a list. `Slicing` or `creating` a new one using `conditional statements` is usually a better practice.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is not a good idea to delete elements from a list you are iterating. In your case, you may consider creating a new list with the result you want:

```
l = ['X','Y','Z','A', 'B:C', 'D']
clean_l = [i for i in l if i not in ('A', 'B:C', 'D')]
```

Which is a good option if you know which elements you want to delete. However, if you know that you don't want anything after 'Z' regardless of their value, then just slice the list:

```
clean_l = l[:l.index('Z') + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you would want to find the position of 'Z' by using the index() method.

```
x = ['X','Y','Z','A', 'B:C', 'D']
position = x.index('Z')
```

Then to delete everything after z i would do this:

```
del x[postion+1:]
```

You have to add one to the position otherwise it will delete 'Z' also

Comment: is that p.index or x.index?